# How to sort by date and time in Finder?

Tags: mac, finder, macos, high-sierra

When I'm in Photoshop or when I try to upload a file to Google Chrome, I want my files to be organized by Date Modified. I have selected that but it group it into Date (Today, Yesterday, Previous 7 Days). How can I then organize them by time (newest at the top, oldest at the bottom)?

[image: Screenshot example]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Arrange toolbar button/menu.

here is the tooltip:

[image]

option+click on it to change the sort order:

[image]

Comment: Wow, you're really on top of things today! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This doesn't arrange by time though. Just the Month

Comment: @nemoryoliver it arranges by date, which includes time.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume here that you want them sorted by date modified, not "organized". The breakup you have right now is "organized" by date modified, but still sorted by name.

At the top towards the left of the finder window, click the button with the four horizontal lines, the one second from the left. Now you'll see that each file has a few columns of information on it. If "Date Modified" does not appear as one of these columns, right click on the column at the top (if right click is not set up, hold the "Control" key while you click), then click "Date Modified". It should now pop up directly to the right of the "Name" column. Click on the "Date Modified" column title to sort the files by date and time modified. If it sorts backwards from the way you want, just click it again, and it will reverse the order of the files.

Comment if you have further questions or if this did not answer your question.

Comment: Yes that works for the view where you click on the "four horizontal lines" but how can I get it to do the same for the "three grid-like boxes" (https://i.imgur.com/j1qdbXe.png)?

Comment: To sort in Column view, click on the Finder's "View" menu, and go to the "Sort By…" submenu, and choose your desired sorting method. This method works for List, Column or Icon view as well.