# How can I have Finder doesn't sort strictly by the time metadata and not the grouped filename?

Tags: macos, finder

See the following screenshot:

[image]

This are screenshots from the Chrome/Safari, on OSX 10.12.1.

Notice that this is clearly not in the right chronological order. The last screenshot was taken at 1:09 PM, but it is neither at the top nor at the beginning of the list. This is frustrating, because this forces me to visually search when I want to send a screenshot I just took to a friend.

Is there any way to change my settings so Finder sorts by date?

Comment: Look at the small little arrow in the Today coulomb, it is pointing UP, means you clicked on Today and it is sorting by Name of the File. Just click on the Date Created and the arrow will now be there and you can sort properly (Up or Down).

Comment: @Buscar웃 is correct. Everything in your view is correct - there are grouping features and you've asked the system to sort by text field - not date metadata. I've edited the question so it's more about how to get Finder to sort chronologically rather than apple or you being right or wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The toolbar specifies how to *group* the files and clicking the column name is for *sorting* the files. If you want to reorder the files, just click the column name directly.

Based on your screenshot, you're grouping by "Date Created" and then sorting by "Name". You can see the group names are "September", "August", etc.

You can fix this: set the grouping (using the toolbar) to "None" and then click on the "Date Created" column name, that should fix your issue.

EDIT: If you're not using the List view, you can press `⌘J` to open "View options", then click the drop-down there to Sort by "Date Created". I know it's annoying, but that's how it is.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Thank you. But then, there is no way to sort by Date Created on the layout with image previews?

Comment: Press `⌘J` to open "View options", then click the dropdown there to Sort by "Date Created". I know it's annoying, but there's no other way if you don't use List view.

Answer (score 0):

All your settings are correct.

But you clicked on the Today column (as shown by the little up/down arrow on the right of it.

[image]

With that you told your Mac to sort it by name.

Just click on the Date Created column to get it sorted by that.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the notes in [éclairevoyant's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/340746/19289) about using Cmd-J to view more detailed options, if you have the toolbar visible, you can also option-click on the Grouping toolbar icon to select Sorting options instead.  (Credit to [this closely related question and answer.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/317102/19289))